# LINQ Except query with an XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data set that I receive from a service. The data comes in XML format. We are given an XElement object with all the data. The structure of the XML document is very simple. Looks like this:

```
<root> 
 <dataPoint>
   <id>1</id>
   <param1>somedata</param1>
   <param2>somedata</param2>
 </dataPoint>
 <dataPoint>
   <id>2</id>
   <param1>somedata</param1>
   <param2>somedata</param2>
 </dataPoint>
</root>
```

Of course, I have a large number of dataPoints. I also have a list (List) with the id's of dataPoints being displayed in a GUI. What I'd like to have is the dataPoints that ARE NOT displayed on the GUI so I can manipulate only those and not the whole data set.
Thanks

Comment: That's not very difficult. You've almost already given the query in plain English: the dataPoints where the id is not in the list of ids shown in the GUI. Give it a try.

Comment: Loved the _Give it a try_. ;)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I realized that was my logic before I posted the question. My syntax was not right though as I had never done LINQ before (or much C# for that matter). I found many examples yesterday but none with XElement and I did not know how to drill down the elements in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var toDisplay = new List<string>() { "2" };

var xDoc = XElement.Load(.....);
var dPoints = xDoc.Descendants("dataPoint")
                    .Where(d => !toDisplay.Contains(d.Element("id").Value));
var newXml = new XElement("root",dPoints).ToString();
```

Comment: He wants the ones not being displayed?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts guys. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a mutable dictionary and giving you a dictionary of points and corresponding nodes:

```
var xml = "<root> \r\n <dataPoint>\r\n   <id>1</id>\r\n   <param1>somedata</param1>\r\n   <param2>so" +
"medata</param2>\r\n </dataPoint>\r\n <dataPoint>\r\n   <id>2</id>\r\n   <param1>somedata" +
"</param1>\r\n   <param2>somedata</param2>\r\n </dataPoint>\r\n</root>";    

var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);  

var pointsInGui = new List<int> {1, 3, 5};  

var dict = doc.Descendants("dataPoint").ToDictionary(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("id").Value));      
foreach (var point in pointsInGui) dict.Remove(point);
```

At this point `dict` contains `2 => <relevant element>`.